# Responsive stacking multi-image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, slider, responsive-slides

I'm looking to do the following:

Have an auto-playing slider that moves 2 slides at a time. The left/top slide will contain live text within a div, and the right/bottom will be just an image. When the browser resizes I'd like the left section to stack on top. When they slide, they'll be replaced by 2 different slides set up the exact same way.

Is there a plug-in or jquery that would make this possible? Or a simple one that I could manipulate?

thank you,
Jordana

Answer (score 0):

youll want a function lke this for the animating simulataneously

```
    $(function () {
        $("#first").animate({
           //youre animation here in the format of
  width: '600px'
        }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
        $("#second").animate({
         //if you want you can change several attributes at once such as
 width: '600px',
 height: '600px'

        }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    });
```

and then you will to set the width of the div or span that your using as a container to a percentage, with css. so it will auto resize try 90%
and play around with it. of course from what you said you will want to change the actual animation parameters to make the first Dom move up and the second Dom to move down.... that should be pretty simple... so i hoope this helps!